# How to fix RegEX pattern to find all matches?

Tags: javascript, regex

I've wrote RegEx pattern

```
const PATTERN = /get id\(\) {\s*return '([^']*)'/;
```

but it finds until first match. I've added **g** flag.

And now instead of getting only ids: 53d69076,99969076,22269076
from text

```
static get id() {
    return '53d69076'
}


static get id() {
    return '99969076'
}

static get id() {
    return '22269076'
}
```

I've got

```
 'get id() {\n        return \'53d69076\'',
 'get id() {\n        return \'99969076\''
 'get id() {\n        return \'22269076\''
```

Could you help me to fix my pattern (to get only ids, not full str)?

result
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCdHB.png)

Comment: Your match is in the first capturing group `$1` see https://regex101.com/r/Yo9RAu/1

Comment: Are you trying to parse javascript with a regex?

Comment: Check picture plz, it doesn't work

Comment: @Smart Hello. Do tell me what you need? Write how neet result.

Comment: Could you add the code that you are trying to your question?

Comment: @Smart What's needed matches?

Comment: @Smart I do answered on your question?

Answer (score 0):

IUUC:

```
/return\s+\'(?<yourCapturedGroup>\w+)\'/
```

you can use the group named yourCapturedGroup to retrieve the ID's using the /g

**EDIT**:
here is the link for the regex101:

```
https://regex101.com/r/0YQIOh/1
```

Comment: I have the result   :   [ 'return \'53d69076\'', 'return \'99969076\'', 'return \'22269076\'' ]

Comment: but I need it without return

Comment: what version of javascript are you using?

Comment: a simple fix would be to use just the \' as markers \' with the regex: `\'\w+\'`
and then you can use str.replace() to take off those extra `'` on the ids

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript RegExp all match

If you want to get all match in RegExp:

- you have to call function `exec` in cycle `while ((match = myRe.exec(str))`
- You should not specify **regular expression** in cycle `while` it should be in variable. It is not right: `while ((match = /([0-9]+?)/gm.exec(str)) != null)`
- You need specify flag `g` and maybe `m`. Exapmle: `/([0-9]+?)/gm`

#### Example how to use function `exec` in JavaScript and get all match from RegExp

```js
var str = "static get id() {\n return '99969076'\n} \n static get id() {\n return '888888'\n} \n static get id() {\n return '777777'\n}";

function getArray(str){
    let match, 
        arr = [],
        myRe = /static get id\(\) {\s*?return '([0-9]+?)'\s*?}/g;

    while ((match = myRe.exec(str)) != null) {
         arr.push(match[1]);
    } 
    return arr.length > 0 ? arr : false;
}

console.log(getArray(str));
console.log(getArray(null));
```

---

#### Example how to use function `replace` in JavaScript and get all match from RegExp

```js
var str = "static get id() {\n return '99969076'\n} \n static get id() {\n return '888888'\n} \n static get id() {\n return '777777'\n}";

function getData(str){
    let arr = [];
    
    if (str == null) { 
        return false; 
    }

    str.replace(/static get id\(\) {\s*?return '([0-9]+?)'\s*?}/g, 
    function(match, p1, offset, str_full){
        return arr.push(p1);
    });
    return arr.length > 0 ? arr : false;
}

console.log(getData(str));
console.log(getData(null));
console.log(getData('fthfthfh'));
```

---

#### Other examples how to use function `replace` in JavaScript

```js
const h = "static get id() {return '99969076'}";
            
console.log(h.replace(/static get id\(\) {return ('[0-9]+?')}/g, '$1'));
```

```js
const h = "static get id() {\n return '99969076'\n}";
            
console.log(h.replace(/static get id\(\) {\s*?return '([0-9]+?)'\s*?}/g, '$1'));
```